# Is storing a doubly linked list in a table wholly redundant?

Tags: sql, postgresql, linked-list

Let's say we have a table called `nodes` with columns `id`, `next_id` &`prev_id`.

For purpose of below, let's also say `$this` is some node in memory being used to form the query.

I observe the following queries can be issued:

***1) "Follow the node's own links":***

```
SELECT * from nodes where id = $this.next_id;
SELECT * from nodes where id = $this.prev_id;
```

***2) "Look up backlinks to this node elsewhere in the table" (foreign keys, obviously)***

This uses the fact that, unlike were this to be a raw datastructure not in a table, in sql we are actually in a table, so we can just look up the backward pointing links (you could not do this on a raw linked list data structure in memory, because there would be no index enabling this)

```
SELECT * from nodes where next_id = $this.id;
SELECT * from nodes where prev_id = $this.id;
```

This leads me to conclude that "links" in sql are effectively bi-directional by default.

I know to some experts this may seem a very elementary point but I believe it worth stressing because it may get to the core of something quite important.

A side issue is I am a little confused that when I search for "doubly linked list in sql", there are a few people talking about doing this. 
Have they simply got it wrong?

Comment: Note:if the list is not cyclic, (at least) one pointer has to be NULL (two for the dll case)

Answer (score 1):

Linked lists -- of the doubly linked sort or not -- are almost never needed in SQL databases.  They are a data structure used to optimize certain types of data access, particularly for data stored in memory.

SQL databases store data using different mechanisms.  Data is stored on data pages, which typically contain multiple records.  Access is improved though the use of indexes, which come in multiple flavors (particularly in Postgres).  The assumption is that data is larger than memory -- although many "smaller" databases now do readily fit into available memory.

What *are* used are foreign key references.  In this case `nodes` could be defined as:

```
create nodes as (
    nodeId serial primary key,
    prev_nodeId int references nodes(nodeId),
    next_nodeId int references nodes(nodeId)
);
```

However, nothing (in this declaration) would guarantee that next-->prev = prev-->next, for instance.  Enforcing that constraint is a little tricky.

What you are really trying to do with a doubly-linked list is to maintain order.  In SQL, you would do that with some sort of ordering column:

```
create nodes as (
    nodeId serial primary key,
    ordering int unique not null
);
```

This would guarantee an ordering.  With this approach, you can get the next and previous using `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
lead(nodeId) over (order by ordering) as next_nodeId
lag(nodeId) over (order by ordering) as prev_nodeId
```

If the linked list is merely used to remember "insertion" order, then `serial` already does that for you and an additional column is not necessary.

In SQL, you get an unordered array of rows automatically when data is in a table.  You can readily add a column that specifies the ordering.  Under these circumstances, linked lists are much less useful.

Comment: I also need to support insert and reordering operations, and the code to do that using an int ordering doesn't seem to be trivial either, hence exploration of the linked list, which seems 'neat' in some respects. Interesting about the window function idea - haven't seen that idea before. wondering in what way that assists here. thanks @Gordon for your answer. I've actually completed the code but am just critiquing it here. May try changing the double to single linked list, mainly to address the fact I've realised it's redundant. This question was mainly to confirm that intuition.

Comment: @mwal . . . If you have a particular problem, then you should ask *another* question describing the problem and providing sample data and desired results.